# How to get pending request in amazon?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am sending request in amazon using **GetReport** API.

**As per amazon document we can send only 15 request per minute.**

How can get from amazon how many number of requests are pending ?

Amazon is providing any API to get this details ?

We are following below amazon document.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_GetReport.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate page describing how request quotas (and therefore throttling) work: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to get details before get_report, like number of request pending 0 . so we don't try to request in amazon..!!!

Comment: You will have to make a call to `GetReport`. That call may fail due to an exceeded quota, but even if it does, it will return the remaining calls as HTTP header. The remaining calls will be 0 if quota was reached already.

Comment: Great.. Solution we are getting values in header..x-mws-quota-remaining,x-mws-quota-max...